# How do I find the centre of mass using calculus, early University problem

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

Small background: I am a mathematician student, currently my first year in university. This problem is a calculus problem. So I am meant to solve this using calculus.

My questions before presenting this problem is; How do I break down this problem? Where do I start? Do you have any tips on what I can do? What would you do when encountering this problem? What can I/others learn in the future doing problems like these?

An homogeneous plate ($\rho $) that lies on a table. The table has the coordinate system $\Omega \:=\:\lbrace a\le x\le b,\:0\le y\le f\left(x\right)\rbrace $, where $f\::\:\left[a,b\right]\:\Longrightarrow \:\mathbb{R}$ is a positive and continuous function.

We know that the center of mass for $\Omega $ is the point $\left(X,Y\right)$ <- (Those are vectors I guess).

If $P$ is a plate that is made by the same material as $\rho $, but extens over the area $\Omega P$, that is defined by $g\left(x\right)=\:\alpha \:f\left(x+\phi \right)$, where is the masscenter to $\rho $?

My first intuition is to find the domain of $P$, but I'm not sure how to do this, and even solve this.

Any help/hints/tips is appreciated!

Thank you very much that this math forum exists : - )

Comment: The figure $P$ is delimited by straight lines $x=a$, $y=0$, $x=b$ and by some curve $y=f(x)$. Step 1: how does this shape change when you replace $f(x)$ with $f(x+\phi)$...? Step 2: how does that new shape change when you replace $f(x+\phi)$ with $\alpha\,f(x+\phi)$...? Step 3: how does the position of the centre of mass change when the figure changes the way you found in steps 1 & 2...?

Comment: P.S. Your guess about $X,Y$ being vectors is wrong – those are simply two real coordinates of the centre of mass. And the question is what $X_{new}, Y_{new}$ are after described transformations as a function of $X,Y,\alpha$ and $\phi$.